# I'm having difficulty finding this web element with Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver to pull data from one website and my goal is to copy and paste that date into another site using python, I am able to pull the data from the 1st site using iFrame + XPATH but on the 2nd site I am failing to locate the exact web element. I pasted it below:

```
<textarea rows="5" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Paste in a list of emails separated by commas or new lines" class="MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-input MuiInputBase-inputMultiline MuiInputBase-inputSizeSmall TextInput-input css-x7mp9n" id="mui-2" style="height: 115px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: edit your question and put your python code pls

Answer (score 0):

2. The site can have more than one iframe.

Comment: the site does not have an iframe unlike the 1st one.

Comment: If you tell me in detail what you want to do, I can help, I also need links to the sites.

Answer (score 0):

If this element is placed in the body of html but not in `iframe` you can try to use one of these approaches:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'mui-2')
```

or

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//textarea[@placeholder="Paste in a list of emails separated by commas or new lines"]')
```

If nothing of these helps we'll need to know more about page structure and the code you are using to interact with it.